# Perl Catalyst: How to use direct SQL in it Or something like named query

Tags: perl, postgresql, catalyst, named-query

I want to know how to use direct SQL in Perl Catalyst Or something like named query.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst%3a%3aModel%3a%3aDBIC%3a%3aSchema). This is explained in [chapter 3 ﬀ. of the tutorial](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTutorial%3a:03_MoreCatalystBasics#DATABASE-ACCESS-WITH-DBIx%3a%3aClass).

Comment: Hi Daxim, Thanks for your comment, But I am still not clear about this,can you provide me some examples, it would be great.

Comment: Please read and work through the manual/tutorial, it comes with examples.